# Is there a way in Xcode to use the built in back nav and custom buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on a project right now where we want want to be able to navigate back and forth between several views, such as below:
[image: navigation with options to cancel or done]

With this, clicking on New Deck (this is a temp button), it takes us to the New Deck view, where the user can fill out info and click Done to submit it, or Cancel to cancel and go back to the Decks view. The issue we had is that the built in navigation- Decks is embedded in a navigation controller- doesn't allow us to attach bar button items, such as the Done button.

Here's an example of a built in nav:
[image: Default navigation]

To get around this, we added a navigation item over the default navigation, which seems to essentially replace it, and gave it bar button items that then snapped into place. But now the default functionality of the left button going back a screen is gone. Is the simplest way to fix this creating an action that dismisses the view when the user clicks cancel? This app is going to have a lot of this type of navigation so it seems weirdly inefficient to have to add this to every view, but we can't think of the ideal way to do it.

Comment: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/14/adding-buttons-to-the-navigation-bar-with-storyboards/ look at this link

Comment: You have some typos like "we want want to", "Is the simplest way to..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access the built-in navigation bar by going into.

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...
```

with this, you need not go create a new nav item.

In any case, you can also get the default back bar item by going into

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem
```